# Insert a row into the table omitting all values?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Suppose I have a table with a serial as primary key and couple of other columns, that are all nullable. Is there any way to insert a new row in that table by omitting all the columns in the insert clause? Since serial is auto-incremental and can be omitted right? The rest of columns can be null and can therefore be omitted too? So theoretically it should be possible somehow. But is it?

Comment: Why the MySQL tag?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: `serial` [should be avoided](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don't_use_serial) in modern Postgres version. Use `identity` instead

Comment: mysql has auto-increment column too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `default values` clause (at least in Postgres):

```
insert into some_table
default values;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f021276d2d533ac5e4ffff684c5e836f)

Comment: For MySQL it will be `insert into test (id) values (null);`

Comment: @Akina But that would insert a NULL value in the `id` column. That should be `insert into test (id) values (default)` if you do need to list a column.

Comment: In MySQL inserting NULL value into autoincremented field causes next value generation.

Comment: *That should be `insert into test (id) values (default)` if you do need to list a column* It is correct too. If you not list the column then you must add `default` for each field: `insert into test values (default, default, default)` - if not then "the amount of values doesn't match the amount of columns" error will be generated.

Comment: Seriously? MySQL silently changes an explicit NULL to something else? That's one non-standard behaviour if I have ever seen one.

Comment: [Using AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html): *(if) No value was specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, so MySQL assigned sequence numbers automatically. You can also explicitly assign 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers, unless the NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO SQL mode is enabled. ... If the column is declared NOT NULL, it is also possible to assign NULL to the column to generate sequence numbers.*

Comment: I think all of this info has to be incorporated into one single answer. That might be.very useful for posterity @Akina

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can I use keyword `default` in general for any kind of column value for which can be omitted? So for - a serial or for a column that has its default set via some other weird function?

Comment: @jayarjo: yes, you can use that for any column. Btw: the need to "merge" comments together is the result of essentially asking two questions: "How do I do this in Postgres (or standard SQL)?" and "How do I do this in MySQL?"

Comment: But I need both :/

Comment: @Akina just found out that this also officially supported by mysql: `INSERT INTO tbl_name () VALUES()`